# How do I draw a G vs T diagram for carbon dioxide?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image: This is the diagram for water]

I learnt that carbon dioxide has the same boiling temperature and sublimation temperature, so all three lines should join together at one point but why does the carbon dioxide have a different melting temperature? And how do I draw the diagram for carbon dioxide?

Answer (score 0):

If it is below the triple point, the 3 lines join at the same point. If it is above, then solid will change to liquid (melting) and liquid to gas (evaporation) are two separate points.